# Annotation support for Guava

Tags: spring, annotations, guava

Is there any support for Annotations in Guava Library like Spring [`AnnotationUtils`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html) class?

Comment: Also See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000480/is-there-commons-annotationutils-like-library-java

Comment: Also Commons Lang 3 added [AnnotationUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/lang3/AnnotationUtils.html) but its rather worthless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at the moment, no, but perhaps you might like to file a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/entry)?

Comment: Done. https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1114 Thanks Louis.